# Limit list data in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to limit list in **for in loop**. if data list more than 8. It just display 8 list. I've add condition like this **if (entry.length <= 8)** but it not working.

```
poweredareaOfInspec(List < Map < String, dynamic >> areaOfInspec) {
    try {
        if (areaOfInspec != null) {
            var areaOfInspecHtml = "";
            for (var entry in areaOfInspec) {
                if (entry.length <= 8) {
                    areaOfInspecHtml += '<tr style="height: 35px;">';
                    areaOfInspecHtml +=
                        '<td align="center" style="font-family: arial; color: #414141;font-size: 12px;border-right: solid 0.7px #d6d5d5;">' +
                        entry['key'] +
                        '</td>';

                    areaOfInspecHtml += '<td align="center" style="font-family: arial; color: #414141;font-size: 12px;">';
                    areaOfInspecHtml += entry['value'].split("#")[0] == "true" ? "&#10003;" : "&#8211;";
                    areaOfInspecHtml += '</td>';

                    areaOfInspecHtml += '<td align="center" style="font-family: arial; color: #414141;font-size: 12px;">';
                    areaOfInspecHtml += entry['value'].split("#")[1] == "true" ? "&#10003;" : "&#8211;";
                    areaOfInspecHtml += '</td>';

                    areaOfInspecHtml += '<td align="center" style="font-family: arial; color: #414141;font-size: 12px;">';
                    areaOfInspecHtml += entry['value'].split("#")[2] == "true" ? "&#10003;" : "&#8211;";
                    areaOfInspecHtml += '</td>';

                    areaOfInspecHtml += '<td align="center" style="font-family: arial; color: #414141;font-size: 12px;">';
                    areaOfInspecHtml += entry['value'].split("#")[3] == "true" ? "&#10003;" : "&#8211;";
                    areaOfInspecHtml += '</td>';
                    areaOfInspecHtml += "</tr>";
                }
            }
            return areaOfInspectionHtml;
        } else {
            log("====*****areaOfInspecHtml not found");
            return '';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw Exception("Error" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The var entry is just a variable not a list. So change your if condition from if(entry.length<=8) to if(areaOfInspec.length<=8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`take`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Iterable/take.html). It will return the first N items in a list (or all of them if the list has fewer than N items):

```dart
for (var entry in areaOfInspec.take(8)) {
  ...
}
```